# Prettier is not formatting C++ in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

Prettier is not formatting c++ code in VS code. I have to manually enter the indentation in the code. I would lie to know how to solve the issue. If it is not possible can someone suggest a code formatter for c++

Answer (score 5):

Prettier wasn't intended to format C++ code. You should install the [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension developed by Microsoft, it supports code formatting.

Details can be found in the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting).

Comment: it still tells me there is no formatter for cpp files installed when pressing ALT+SHIFT+F

Comment: Is there any way I can keep Prettier as default code formatter and a different code formatter for C++?